# Why MySQL connection lost in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am creating a facebook chatbot using node js and to store data I used MySQL Database. Currently it is working fine. But, I have a question that, should I need to close the database connection?

I tried to do it but when I close the connection then in the next attempt it is throwing an error that No SQL Connection found

Please tell me the correct way of how to close database connection and reuse it

```
let databaseConnection = () =>{
    let conn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "",
        user: "",
        password: "",
        database: "",
        port: ""
    });

    conn.connect(function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error when connecting to db ",error);
            setTimeout(databaseConnection, 2000);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Connected");
        }
    });

    conn.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('db error', err);
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            databaseConnection();
        }else{
            throw err; 
        }
    });
    
    return conn;
}

conn = databaseConnection();

for (let i=0;i<10;i++){
    query = "SELECT name FROM info where id=?";
    value = i
    conn.query(query,value, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Data Fetched Successfully.")
    })
    conn.end()
}
```

Comment: Because calling `.end()` terminates the connection?  Have you tried not calling `.end()` when you still want to use the connection?

Comment: @David Actually I am using it in a chatbot. Is it necessary to close the connection? There  are 10k - 50k people are going to interact with chatbot

Comment: Well, closing the connection closes the connection.  So if you want to keep the connection open then it's not necessary to close the connection.  Whether or not this will impact application performance is something you can test and potentially re-design accordingly.

Comment: @David okay tysm for this advice sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You should end your connection after the loop

```
for (let i=0;i<10;i++){
    query = "SELECT name FROM info where id=?";
    value = i
    conn.query(query,value, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Data Fetched Successfully.")
    })
}
conn.end()
```

Comment: Actually I am using it in a chatbot. So if any one user will complete his task and then if I close the connection then other user is not able to create new connection